# How to print multiple pages in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a form with labels and a datagridview, and I want to print the contents. To that end, I've written the following:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pen, new Point(818, y), new Point(818, y + 35));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(770, y + 7), format1);
    y += 35;
    if (y > e.PageBounds.Height - 25)
    {
        y = 50;
        e.HasMorePages = true;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
    i++;
}
```

It works when there is only one page, but subsequent pages are duplicates of the first page. When I remove the `return` statement, I get all the data, but on one page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Move the declaration for `i` outside of that print method, so that the next time it enters the print method again, it will start where it left off.

Comment: Thank you LarsTech. The problem had solved.